# No logro hacer que un Toolbar parezca que está flotando

Tags: android, android-layout

estoy usando Android Studio y quiero que una Toolbar tenga un sombreado en la parte inferior para dar la ilusión de que está flotando, no lo he logrado, probé con elevation y no se nota ningún cambio.

Dejo algunos detalles:

- Uso Pixel 3A para la simulación, tiene API 34.
- Version 1.9.0 de Android material

Código de activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadowView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.5dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Intenté creando shape´s, usando styles, poniendo clipchildren: false, nada funcionó.

Esto es lo que busco lograr:
[image: Este es mi objetivo]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que definiendo "elevation" debe funcionar. Define `app:elevation="0dp"` en el `AppBarLayout` y la respectiva elevación en tu `Toolbar`

```
...
...
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

       <!-- <View
            android:id="@+id/shadowView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.5dp"/> -->

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
...
...
```

Comment: Buenas Jorge, hice lo que mencionas y al menos en el Split no funciona (desconozco  si al ejecutar la aplicación y en la simulación sea distinto?) El toolbar se muestra pero no se muestra ningún tipo de sombra abajo

Comment: @Kalio en que sistema operativo estas probando esto?

Comment: El celular: Pixel 3A con Api 34
Mi sistema operativo: Windows 10

Comment: API 34, ya estás usando la versión beta de Android 14 :o, probablemente eso sea el problema.

Comment: Voy a probar con una versión mas vieja de Android para comprobar

Comment: Probé con la API 33 y con la API 31 y la sombra sigue sin aparecer, es extraño